# Is there a way for an NSView to know when its window is closed?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsview, nswindow

I'm working on an NSView subclass and I'd like to know when its window is closed so I can do certain housekeeping tasks. What is the standard way to do this? If possible, I'd like to do this within the NSView subclass since I'd like to be able to use this subclass elsewhere without other dependencies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override `-viewDidMoveToWindow` and, if `self.window` is not `nil`, have the view start observing the `NSWindowWillCloseNotification` notification from the window.

Likewise, override `-viewWillMoveToWindow:` and, if `self.window` is not `nil`, stop observing that notification for that window.

Answer (score 1):

You can perhaps create an extending method for [`viewWillDisappear`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSViewController/viewWillDisappear)?

According to the doc description:

> This method is called when:
>
> - The view is about to be removed from the view hierarchy of the window
> - The view is about to be hidden or obscured, such as in the case of a view controller whose parent is a tab view controller and the user switched to another tab
> - **The window is being closed**

However, this is for `NSViewController`, not `NSView`.